Can I use CTE in SQL Server to calculate average utilization rate for months in which customer utilization activities were conducted
I have an exam about creating a list of a company's customers whose utilization rate is low (meaning company needs provide customer services), in SQL Server. I tried many times, but it never worked. Please help!
To support the 'U50%' program, managers need a list of customers with the average utilization rate in the six most recent months from December 2022.
Please use SQL to export a list of customers according to management's requirements, including the following information:

Cust_ID: Customer ID
Contact_date: Date when Cust_ID was created
Customer_type: NTB - Customers who opened Cust_ID in 2023, ETB- Customers who opened Cust_ID before 2023
Utilization Rate in the six most recent months for each customer (Data for each month)
Average Utilization_Rate over the past 6 months, calculated only for months in which customer utilization activities were conducted.

Here is the data: Cust_ID, Contact_date, Utilization_Rate are nvarchar, Month is float



Cust_ID
CONTACT_DATE
Utilization_Rate
Month




Cust7
07/07/2008
Null
202206


Cust52
05/10/2009
0%
202207


Cust53
15/03/2012
1.3%
202212



Seems that the Try_convert doesn't work. My attempts:
WITH DATE_CORRECTED AS (
    SELECT 
        Cust_ID,
        CAST(Month_ID as datetime) AS Month_ID_new
    FROM [dbo].['Raw Data$']
  
),
AVERAGE AS (
SELECT 
CUST_ID,  
Avg(TRY_CONVERT(decimal, Utilization_rate)) as Avg_U_rate, TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL,Utilization_Rate) AS New_Utilization_rate
FROM [dbo].['Raw Data$']
GROUP BY Cust_ID, Utilization_Rate
   ),
CUSTOMER_TYPE AS (
    SELECT 
        Cust_ID,
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(Month_ID_new)= 2023 THEN 'NTB'
            ELSE 'ETB'
        END AS Customer_type
    FROM DATE_CORRECTED
) 
SELECT 
    C.Cust_ID,
    A.Month_ID_new,
    C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
    B.Avg_U_rate,
    B.New_Utilization_rate
FROM CUSTOMER_TYPE C
JOIN AVERAGE B ON C.Cust_ID = B.CUST_ID
JOIN DATE_CORRECTED A ON C.Cust_ID = A.Cust_ID
WHERE MONTH(A.Month_ID_new) >= 6 AND MONTH(A.Month_ID_new) <= 12 and New_Utilization_rate is not null AND New_Utilization_rate < 0.5


I think you need more examples in your data to fully test your query. You need multiple rows per customer to see the affect Avg has.

Yes I do have multiple rows, This is just the demo of the data from the exam. The Contact_date and Utilization_rate is nvarchar and Month_ID is float.

You have 2 problems to correct

The Customer Type subquery must use DateCorrected instead of rawdata and change Contact_date to Contact_date_new
The final WHERE clause restricts A.CONTACT_DATE_new >= '2023-06-01'
All of your dates are between  2008 and 2012

fiddle
WITH DATE_CORRECTED AS (
    SELECT 
        Cust_ID,
        CONVERT(DATE, CONTACT_DATE, 103) AS Contact_date_new
    FROM RawData
   
),
AVERAGE AS (
SELECT 
CUST_ID,  AVG(CAST(Utilization_Rate as DECIMAL(5,2))) as AVG_U_rate, min(Utilization_Rate) as Utilization_Rate
FROM RawData
    --WHERE  try_convert(numeric(38, 12), Utilization_Rate) is null and Utilization_Rate is not null
GROUP BY CUST_ID    
   ),
CUSTOMER_TYPE AS (
    SELECT 
        Cust_ID,
        CASE 
            WHEN YEAR(Contact_date_new)= 2022 THEN 'NTB'
            ELSE 'ETB'
        END AS Customer_type
    FROM DATE_CORRECTED
) 
SELECT 
    C.Cust_ID,
    A.Contact_date_new,
    C.CUSTOMER_TYPE,
    B.AVG_U_rate,
    B.Utilization_Rate
FROM CUSTOMER_TYPE C
JOIN AVERAGE B ON C.Cust_ID = B.CUST_ID
JOIN DATE_CORRECTED A ON C.Cust_ID = A.Cust_ID




Cust_ID
Contact_date_new
CUSTOMER_TYPE
Avg_U_rate
Utilization_Rate




Cust52
2009-10-05
ETB
0.000000
0.00


Cust53
2012-03-15
ETB
1.300000
1.30


Cust7
2008-07-07
ETB
null
null




Thanks but I tried to fix accordingly but still error "Invalid column name 'Contact_date' ". Do you have any ideas?

@minh tue change Contact_date to Contact_date_new

@BartMcEndree Sorry, I forgot to calculate the average rate, I added to the code as above but still error as "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for avg operator."

@minh tue I updated the query.  I think we should use Utilization_Rate decimal(5,2)  in the tabel definition. what datatype do you use for Utilization_Rate  via 'Raw Data$'?

Cust_ID, Contact_date, Utilization_Rate are nvarchar, Month is float. I tried the edited code as above but it didn't work

@minh tue Answer updated to use the data types provided

It's still Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

@minh tue Did you try the updated fiddle which has Utilization_Rate NULL instead of 'NULL' ?

Yes I did. It's stulii not working

@minh tue I don't understand how we could get different results from the same fiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/XQdmz1su
