Can I convert value with multiple format: text, number, date, custom to number at the same time in Excel?
I am cleaning data as below. The raw data column has multiple formats: text, number, date, custom so it's hard to convert all of them at the same time. Can you help me pls?



Raw date
Raw format
Target date
Target format




20051231
Text
20051231
Number


20051231
Number
20051231
Number


31-Dec-05
Custom/number
20051231
Number


2005-12-31
Date
20051231
Number



=IF(ISTEXT(A12),VALUE(TEXT(A12,"YYYYMMDD")),IF(ISNONTEXT(A12),A12,VALUE(A12)))


for the 4 your provided the following works:
=IF(--A1>100000,--A1,--TEXT(A1,"yyyymmdd"))


or this that spills
=LET(m,--A1:A4,IF(m>100000,m,--TEXT(m,"yyyymmdd")))


Thank you so much! It works. As I still don't figure it out can you pls also explain the function of "--" before each clause?

If possible, can you check out my question about SQL pls? I am so stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78555808/can-i-use-cte-in-sql-server-to-calculate-average-utilization-rate-for-months-in?noredirect=1#comment138491619_78555808

@minhtue -- is double unary.  It turns a number stored as text into a number.

Thanks a lot! Pls help me with the SQL question., I am hopeless :((

So this works for me:


• Formula used in cell B2
=--TEXT(--TEXT(--A2:A5,{"0000\/00\/00";"0000\/00\/00";"mm/dd/e";"mm/dd/e"}),"emmdd")


Another alternative bit shorter than the earlier:

=LET(α, --A2:A5, IF(LEN(α)=8,α,--TEXT(α,"emmdd")))



LEN(α)=8 may return true if there is a time factor

@ScottCraner Sir, I agree with you. But OP has not stated anything about, if it does they need to be specific about their post. And from the formula or context, it shows they are dealing with dates.

I agree, The note was for future readers.

@ScottCraner Sir, I am not denying what you have suggested you are right as always.

@ScottCraner Sir, found this one also working: =LET(α, A2:A5, --IFERROR(TEXT(α,"emmdd"),α)
